# use a type object with strongly typed methods

Tags: c#, reflection, strong-typing

I'm not even sure if this would be possible, but here is the problem I'm facing.

Basically I have a strongly typed methods as follow

```
ConsoleHelper.Start<T>() where T:IService
```

What I would like to achieve is to dynamically load T using reflection, so something along the line of

```
var type = Assembly.Load("assembly").GetType("type");
```

then use that type with the strongly typed method defined above. Is this at all possible?

Comment: Could you share a large code snippet that would showcase what are you going to do with var type and part of what generic class ConsolerHelper.Start() where T : IService is?

Comment: The ConsoleHelper is actually a Generic Console App that hosts my WCF services. At the moment, for each WCF service solution, we have a separate TestHost project which essentially does the same thing. So I'm looking for a way to consolidating these TestHost projects into one single project, this project will load up the WCF service assembly using reflection at runtime.

Comment: why don't you want to start several hosts inside one process?

Comment: this is only for development purposes. In a PROD environment, we would have these services hosted as windows services, however in a DEV environment, we host these as console app, hence the TestHost project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can use [MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx) to do this.

```
var startMethod = typeof(ConsoleHelper).GetMethod("Start");

// Equivalent of Start<SomeType>
var typedStartMethod = startMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(SomeType));
```